# Determining the degree of confidence of a Prediction

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, recurrent-neural-network

I'm handling a text multi class classification problem using RNN LSTM and model is pretty accurate (approximately 95%). But I'm interested in finding the degree of accuracy of a Prediction. Can I make a function that can take the probabilities of a single prediction for each class and then output a degree of confidence?

For example 
I've a 4 class classification problem. I built a model and test it over a single Prediction. Probabilities for that Prediction came out to be [0.2, 0.36,  0.1, 0.34] respectively for each class. Prediction will be 2 by the model. But class 4 and class 2 are very close and therefore the degree of confidence should be low for this Prediction as the model is not very confident.

What would be the best function for the above measurement?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Interestingly I came to ask same question, just that I am using XGboost, and also, I have some thoughts around it. Although prediction probabilities are important, alone, they may not be enough. A measure of - how the prediction probability changes by including some noise or by removing some of the data for a particular example should also be included. I am struggling on how to quantify that.

Comment: Also, before we can create a function to calculate it, how would you define it. What would be a good measure of confidence in prediction.

Comment: Here's my current approach. I'm sorting the probabilities and taking the difference of pairwise order and dividing it by their pairwise sum. Also, multiplying an exponential decay term which acts as a weight given to lower probabilities as we go down since we're not concerned with the lower probabilities. Summing all these ends up in a score which I later scaled between the range [0,1]. But I found this approach naive.